# Windows System Files Loadup Process

Tags: windows, boot

Is there a way to find out which order Microsoft Windows XP loads its system files that are stored in the system32 directory, I mean right from the start of the PC booting up.

I need this for troubleshooting purposes and to create a map of windows buttons and dialog boxes.

I have head different wikipedia articles but it is giving conflicting information

Comment: Enable boot logging. See [Advanced Boot Options](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsag/p/advanced-boot-options.htm)

Comment: Thanks, this worked, the log file is at C:\windows\ntbtlog.log.

Comment: Great. Writing up an answer.

Comment: the only files other than .sys files are: ntkrnlpa.exe, hal.dll, KDCOM.DLL and BOOTVID.dll.

There should be more than this but isnt :S lets just assume I have logged in and from that point dont click or do anything, what files are loaded for the OS in that case. excluding third party drivers, startup scripts etc. Only system files.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to find out which order Microsoft Windows XP loads its system files?

You can enable boot logging (which will create a file `C:\windows\ntbtlog.log`):

> 1. Press <kbd>F8</kbd> as the Windows splash screen begins to load to access Advanced Boot Options menu.
>
>    - This method of accessing the "Advanced Boot Options" menu applies to all versions of Windows that includes the menu, including Windows
>        7, Windows Vista, Windows XP, etc.
>    - In Windows XP, this menu is called the "Windows Advanced Options" Menu.

[image]

> 2. Select "Enable Boot Logging" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>
>    - The Enable Boot Logging option will keep a log of the drivers being loaded during the Windows boot process.
>    - If Windows fails to start, you can reference this log and determine which driver was last successfully loaded, or first unsuccessfully
>        loaded, giving you a starting point for your troubleshooting.

Source [Advanced Boot Options](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsag/p/advanced-boot-options.htm)